# How do I perform a SHA512 hash in C++ WinRT?

Tags: c++, windows-runtime

What is the equivalent of the C# method [SHA512CryptoServiceProvider.ComputeHash()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s02tk69a.aspx) in C++ WinRT?

Comment: There isn't one, you'll either have to write it yourself, or get hold of a library to do it instead.

Comment: Since it is C++, can't you use a 3rd party library, such as Crypto++?

Comment: I can consume C# assemblies from the WinRT app too, but the SHA512CryptoServiceProvider does not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [`Windows.Security.Cryptography.Core.CryptographicHash`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.cryptography.core.cryptographichash.aspx) and friends.  There is an example on that page demonstrating one usage, and the documentation for related classes and functions have examples as well.

For a "complete" example, you can take a look at the [`compute_sha1_hash`](http://cxxreflect.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/2ab4aa208c09#cxxreflect%2fwindows_runtime%2fdetail%2fruntime_utility.cpp) function from my Boost-licensed CxxReflect library.  It computes an SHA1 hash; computing an SHA512 hash should simply require changing the requested hash algorithm from "SHA1" to "SHA512".  Note that this function is written using WRL, not C++/CX, though converting the code to C++/CX should be straightforward and would result in much more succinct code.