# How to create SHA-256 hashes in WinRT?

Tags: .net, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store

I went to create a simple one-way SHA-256 hash in WinRT today and realized it didn't work. I did a validation and apparently got this:

> ◦API System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Managed in MSCORLIB,
>   PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application
>   type. CryptoWinRT.exe calls this API. ◦API
>   System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithm in MSCORLIB,
>   PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application
>   type. CryptoWinRT.exe calls this API. ◦API
>   System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Managed.#ctor in MSCORLIB,
>   PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application
>   type. CryptoWinRT.exe calls this API. ◦API
>   System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithm.ComputeHash(System.Byte[])
>   in MSCORLIB, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this
>   application type. CryptoWinRT.exe calls this API.

What is the replacement for this? And why would such a trivial thing not be allowed in WinRT?

Comment: Duplicate of [How do I perform a SHA512 hash in C++ WinRT?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12355417/how-do-i-perform-a-sha512-hash-in-c-winrt) (Different hash algorithm, but the answer is the same.)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
    private void HandleHashClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // get the text...
        var inputText = this.textInput.Text;

        // put the string in a buffer, UTF-8 encoded...
        IBuffer input = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(inputText, 
            BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8);

        // hash it...
        var hasher = HashAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm("SHA256");
        IBuffer hashed = hasher.HashData(input);

        // format it...
        this.textBase64.Text = CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToBase64String(hashed);
        this.textHex.Text = CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToHexString(hashed);
    }
```

Comment: I actually ended up doing almost exactly this. I just never came back to here and posted an answer