# Java MessageDigest class in C#

Tags: c#, encryption

I require a certain piece of encryption logic done in Java to be converted to C#

What would be the C# equivalent for the MessageDigest **update** , **Digest** and **reset** functions ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In C#, the class is [HashAlgorithm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hashalgorithm.aspx).

The equivalent to update is either `TransformBlock(...)` or `TransformFinalBlock(...)`, after the final block version is called (you can also use an empty input) you can call the `Hash` property that will give you the digest value.

`HashAlgorithm` is likely to be reusable after final block is called (which means it is reset for the next time you call `TransformBlock`), you can double check if your `HashAlgorithm` supports reusing at all by checking the property `CanReuseTransform`.

The equivalent to your reset()/digest() combo is a one line `byte[] ComputeHash(byte[])`.

Comment: Just to make sure, The equivalent of 
messageDigest,update(inputBuffer, offset, length) 
would be
hash.TransfomBlock( inputBuffer, offset, length, inputBuffer, offset)?
It would seem so from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.hashalgorithm.transformblock?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 4):

```
try {
      MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
      md.update(password.getBytes());
      BigInteger hash = new BigInteger(1, md.digest());
      hashword = hash.toString(16);
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
      /* error handling */
}
return hashword;
```

```
public static string HashPassword(string input)
{
    var sha1 = SHA1Managed.Create();
    byte[] inputBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input);
    byte[] outputBytes = sha1.ComputeHash(inputBytes);
    return BitConverter.ToString(outputBytes).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
}
```

Comment: Add little bit of comments about your answer. It helped me to generate digest in C#.

Answer (score 1):

For a Digest in C#, similar to Java, you can use the class Windows.Security.Cryptography.Core. E.g., the following method returns a SHA256 hash, formatted in base64:

```
public static string sha256Hash(string data)
{
    // create buffer and specify encoding format (here utf8)
    IBuffer input = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(data,
    BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8);

    // select algorithm
    var hasher = HashAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm("SHA256");
    IBuffer hashed = hasher.HashData(input);

    // return hash in base64 format
    return CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToBase64String(hashed);
}
```

See (mbrit): [How to create SHA-256 hashes in WinRT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12503032/how-to-create-sha-256-hashes-in-winrt)