# What is the equivalent of the Java method 'MessageDigest.getInstance()' in c# ?

Tags: c#, java, cryptography, sha

What is the equivalent of this in C#?

```
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");    
byte[] after = md.digest(before);    
String securityHash =new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode(after);
```

The source is in Java

Comment: What have you tried so far? What are you stuck on? (Also, normally it's a good idea to mention the source language -- I'm guessing this is Java?)

Comment: The source is in Java

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I was looking for the same. I came across another post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15470738/java-messagedigest-class-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

The [`System.Security.Cryptography`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.md5cryptoserviceprovider.aspx) namespace is a high level analogue of `MessageDigest`. For example, you can use [`MD5CryptoServiceProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.md5cryptoserviceprovider.aspx) to compute MD5 hash like this:

```
MD5 md = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
after = md.ComputeHash(before)
```