# Could not load type 'System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Managed' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, cryptography, paytm

when i tried creating checksum for paytm in my UWP app

`paytm.CheckSum.generateCheckSumByJson("OYxxxxxxxxxxxx", first_json);`

i am getting the following issue :

> paytm.exception.CryptoException: 'Exception occurred while generating
>   CheckSum. Could not load type
>   'System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Managed' from assembly 'mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e'.'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12503032/how-to-create-sha-256-hashes-in-winrt

Comment: Not sure, that it's available for UWP, you can have a look at `
Windows.Security.Cryptography.Core` assembly and namespace

Comment: Included the `` Windows.Security.Cryptography.Core`` but no use

Answer (score 0):

`SHA256Managed` is part of `'System.Security.Cryptography'`. Try installing the nuget package and check if you have the dll's.

Comment: Referenced `'System.Security.Cryptography' `  the same response again